# replace linear-gradient percentage by using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my first time to use regex,  I would like to replace the second rgb percentage from 10% to 30%. Such as `rgb(251, 188, 5) 10%` to `rgb(251, 188, 5) 30%`

I've tried to search through online, but couldn't get what I really need. below is my testing code, I am only able to get the `rgb(251, 188, 5)`, how can I include the `10%` for me to replace it? or direct access to the 10% and replace it to 30%?

before change:

```
linear-gradient(rgb(251, 188, 5), rgb(251, 188, 5) 10%, rgb(223, 223, 223) 0%, rgb(223, 223, 223) 100%)
```

expected result:

```
linear-gradient(rgb(251, 188, 5), rgb(251, 188, 5) 30%, rgb(223, 223, 223) 0%, rgb(223, 223, 223) 100%)
```

```js
const r = "linear-gradient(rgb(251, 188, 5), rgb(251, 188, 5) 10%, rgb(223, 223, 223) 0%, rgb(223, 223, 223) 100%)".replace(/(?<=rgb.*?)rgb\(.*?\)/, '30%')
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
.replace(/^(.*?\brgb.*?\brgb\([^()]*\)\s*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%/, '$130%')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJbupR/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?\brgb.*?\brgb\([^()]*\)\s*)` - Group 1 (`$1`):

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `\brgb.*?` - a word boundary and `rgb` and any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `\brgb\(` - `rgb` whole word and `(` char
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits, and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits (not necessary for the current example, but good to have if you have numbers with fractional parts)
- `%` - (actually, it is here to just assure we have a percentage value, it might not be necessary) - a `%` char.

JavaScript demo:

```js
console.log(
  "linear-gradient(rgb(251, 188, 5), rgb(251, 188, 5) 10%, rgb(223, 223, 223) 0%, rgb(223, 223, 223) 100%)".replace(/^(.*?\brgb.*?\brgb\([^()]*\)\s*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%/, '$130%')
)
```